# Swagger UI {format} Property?

Tags: ruby, swagger, swagger-ui, ruby-grape

I'm looking at a Swagger UI that shows this:

[image]

I don't know what the `{format}` "segment" is or what it is for. I thought maybe it is related to this [piece of Swagger documentation](http://swagger.io/specification/) (under the "Data Types" heading):

> Primitives have an optional modifier property `format`

However, I believe I've found this `format` modifier in my own swagger.json content, and it certainly does not appear in my swagger UI.  For example, my swagger.json often contains this:

> operationId":"ApiValuesByIdGet","produces":[],"parameters":[{"name":"id","in":"path","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int32"}]

So why the "funny business" in the image above?

I'm told that the endpoint providing the API is written in Ruby or Grape.  Also, the swagger.json it is returning shows that it is SwaggerVersion 1.2.

I do notice that the Swagger UI also shows an error in the bottom right corner.  When I select the error link, it shows the detail:

> {"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Deprecated Swagger version.  Please visit http://swagger.io for information on upgrading to Swagger 2.0\""}]}

I don't know if this error is related.

Ultimately I just want to know a likely explanation of what the `{format}` segment signifies (it looks like a path template).  Right now I'm thinking it is malformed swagger.json, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: Search for "Data Types" here http://swagger.io/specification/

Comment: @SiKing Ya, that is precisely the part of the documentation I was quoting.  I've clarified my question to indicate that.

Comment: response format, usually json or html or xml. Some servers assume a default response type if not explicitly specified

Comment: @prusswan It is the duty of the `accept` header to specify response format.  I doubt Swagger has created a way to avoid using HTTP correctly.  Are you sure about your answer?  Can you point to documentation that corroborates?

Comment: @BrentArias What version is your Swagger document? What about your Swagger UI?

Comment: @NavidShakibapour It is version 1.2 (I now updated my question to show this).  I don't know what version the Swagger UI is...I've not seen anything in the html which indicates its version.

Comment: I looked at it again, it depends on the intention of the person who defined this path. I still think that it is meant as a response format, and not the `format` as defined for swagger. e.g. id.json could fetch the data in json, while id.html leads to a page